# Cannot find symbol method setText() and getText() with spinner

Tags: java, android

I'm having a hard time using spinner to create a checkbox in my project.

The files `RegisterBook.java` and `BookAdapter.java` return errors. these errors involve `getText()`, `getSelectedItem()(for condition disallow default option)` and `setText(string)`.

Spinner doesn't exist these `setText()` and `getText()` methods, I don't know which proper methods I should use.

- File `string.xml`

```
    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">Bookapp</string>
         <string-array name="spinnerOptions_book">
              <item> Choose the book category </item>
              <item> Biography </item>
              <item> Education </item>
              <item> Literature </item>
              <item> HQ, Graphic Novel, Manga </item>
         </string-array>
    </resources>
```

- File `activity_register_book.xml`

```
    <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerCategory_book"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:contentDescription="Checkbox to choose the book category"
            android:entries="@array/spinnerOptions_book"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="181dp" />
```

- File `RegisterBook.java`

```
    Spinner spinnerCategory_book;
    
    spinnerCategory_book = findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory_book);
    
    //error: cannot find symbol method getText()
    String category_book = spinnerCategory_book.getText().toString();
    
    //error: cannot find symbol method getSelectedItem()
    if (category_book.getSelectedItem().equals("Choose the book category")){
        Toast.makeText(RegisterBook.this,"No form fields can be empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

- File `BookAdapter.java`

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Book f_book = books.get(position);
        // error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)
        holder.spinnerCategory_book.setText(f_book.getCategory_book());
    });
```

Comment: The `Spinner` class has no such methods (`setText` and `getText`); what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Andy i'm trying to correct these methods, I thought that Spinner accepted these methods.

Comment: For the "get" I'd guess what you want is `spinnerCategory_book.getSelectedItem().toString()` and the conditional is simply `category_book.equals("...").

Comment: @Andy your comments have been helpful, almost all errors have been corrected. But still the error in the ```holder.spinnerCategory_book.setText(f_book.getCategory_book());``` line still persists.

Comment: @Andy from the ```BookAdapter.java``` file.